# ¿Cómo mostrar solo los registros de una tabla con nombres del campo y no su id si que salgan duplicados los resultados?

Tags: sql, postgresql

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una tabla en postgresql y necesito realizar una consulta que me devuelva las tuplas con sus respectivas relaciones pero en vez de mostrar los id necesito ver los nombres, entonces realizo la siguiente consulta

```
select i.id, p.codigo_barras, p.descripcion, pro.nombre, u.user_name, fecha, hora, cantidad from ingresos_mercancias i, productos p, proveedores pro, users u
```

cuando hago la consulta me esta regresando demasiadas tuplas y veo que salen repetidas cuando la tabla **ingresos_mercancias** solo tiene 5 tuplas

¿Como hago para que me regrese solo las 5 tuplas y en vez de los id me ponga los campos que quiero?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen muestro lo que me sale

y asi me sale cuando uso distintc 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estas son las tablas en cuestion

```
CREATE TABLE familias( 
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(50), 
  CONSTRAINT pkfamilias PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);

CREATE TABLE marcas(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nombre character varying(50), 
  CONSTRAINT pkmarcas PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE productos(
  id serial NOT NULL, -- Código del producto
  id_marca integer NOT NULL,
  id_familia integer NOT NULL,
  codigo_barras varchar,
  descripcion varchar(80), -- Descripcion del producto
  precio_costo double precision, -- Precio de costo del producto
  precio_venta double precision, -- Precio mayorista del producto
  precio_mayorista double precision, -- Precio mayorista del producto
  precio_credito double precision, -- Precio crédito del producto
  unidad_medida varchar(9),
  cant_paquete integer, -- Cantidad por paquete del producto
  iva integer, -- Cantidad por paquete del producto
  observaciones varchar(200),
  descuento double precision, -- Precio mayorista del producto
  stock integer, -- Precio mayorista del producto
  CONSTRAINT clave_primaria PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_familia FOREIGN KEY (id_familia) REFERENCES familias (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_marca FOREIGN KEY (id_marca) REFERENCES marcas (id)
  );

CREATE TABLE proveedores (
  id serial  primary key,
  nombre varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  nit_documento varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  direccion varchar(80),
  contacto varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  contacto2 varchar(20),
  sitio_web varchar(50),
  email varchar(50)
);
CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial  primary key,
  nombre varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  password varchar NOT NULL,
  user_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  direccion varchar(80),
  telefono varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  telefono2 varchar(20),
  sitioweb varchar(50),
  estado char(1),
  email varchar(50),
  id_perfil int,
  constraint fk_perfil foreign key (id_perfil) references perfiles (id)
);

CREATE TABLE ingresos_mercancias(
  id serial NOT NULL, -- Código de la factura cabecera
  id_producto integer, -- Código del cliente en la factura cabecera
  id_proveedor integer, -- Código del cliente en la factura cabecera
  id_user integer, -- Código del cliente en la factura cabecera
  fecha date, -- Fecha de emisión de la factura
  hora varchar(8),
  cantidad integer, -- Monto total a pagar
  precio_entrada double precision, -- Estado de la factura
  CONSTRAINT pk_ingresos PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_producto FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES productos (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_proveedor FOREIGN KEY (id_proveedor) REFERENCES proveedores (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id_useri FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

Comment: Podrías describir exactamente la estructura de tus tablas en cuestión y cual es la relación entre ellas?

Comment: Hola, ya edite la pregunta y anexe el codigo

Comment: Intenta realizar un inner join de la siguiente manera: select i.id, p.codigo_barras, p.descripcion, pro.nombre, u.user_name, fecha, hora, cantidad from ingresos_mercancias inner join productos on ingresos_mercancias.idserial = productos.idserial inner join proveedores on proveedores.id = productos.idserial inner join users on users.id_user = ingresos_mercancias.id_user; Asegurate de Corregir el nombre de los campos.

Comment: Perfecto me funciono, aunque tuve que modificar un poco las tablas, la consulta quedo así

select ingresos_mercancias.id, productos.codigo_barras, productos.descripcion, proveedores.nombre, users.user_name, fecha, hora, cantidad from ingresos_mercancias inner join productos on ingresos_mercancias.id_producto = productos.id inner join proveedores on proveedores.id = ingresos_mercancias.id_proveedor inner join users on users.id = ingresos_mercancias.id_user order by fecha;

Comment: Ok, lo agrego como respuesta, para que la marques como correcta y puedas ayudarme con mi reputación :)

Comment: listo, campeon, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
select ingresos_mercancias.id, productos.codigo_barras, productos.descripcion, proveedores.nombre, users.user_name, fecha, hora, cantidad from ingresos_mercancias inner join productos on ingresos_mercancias.id_producto = productos.id inner join proveedores on proveedores.id = ingresos_mercancias.id_proveedor inner join users on users.id = ingresos_mercancias.id_user order by fecha;
```

Answer (score 1):

Te falta utilizar el where con las referencias de cada fk(productos p, proveedores pro, users u) con su pk

Ya que te está mostrando de acuerdo al resultado de cada tabla-

```
  select i.id, p.codigo_barras, p.descripcion, pro.nombre, u.user_name, fecha, hora, cantidad from ingresos_mercancias i, productos p, proveedores pro, users u where p.id_serial = i.id_producto and pro.id_serial = i.id_proveedor and u.id serial = i.id_user
```

Saludos.

Comment: Si me faltaba eso jajajajajaja la verdad no me había dado cuenta que me faltaba el where, que bruto yo jajajaja en serio no creo que se me halla olvidado algo tan elemental y fácil

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre una solucion y fue con inner join, acá dejo la consulta que use y ima imagen de los resultados

Gracias por ayudar

```
 select ingresos_mercancias.id, productos.codigo_barras, productos.descripcion, proveedores.nombre, users.user_name, fecha, hora, cantidad from ingresos_mercancias inner join productos on ingresos_mercancias.id_producto = productos.id inner join proveedores on proveedores.id = ingresos_mercancias.id_proveedor inner join users on users.id = ingresos_mercancias.id_user order by fecha;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]